# Counting the number of http requests in javascript

Tags: javascript, tomcat, httprequest, google-chrome-devtools

Is there a way in javascript to count the number of http request that a website does to a server?
EXAMPLE: In my local webserver running with apache tomcat i have a simple html page helloworld.html with a style.css file, so when i type "localhost:8080/helloworld.html" the browser does two requests, one for helloworld.html and one for style.css.

My goal is to show this number on helloworld.html for a video element, when i play it start several number of http get to the webserver.

I'm trying for several days on the web but I have not found anything. I found webrequest api but i think that only chrome extension can use it. I found also chrome.devtools.network API but i can use it only when chrome dev tools is opened.

Comment: Surely the place to do this is one the server, it will log all requests

Comment: You're right but i want to show this number on my html page.

Comment: Even on the server it's tricky because you need to associate all the individual http requests with the one initial one. If you *can* do it server-side, you can then write the data to a file, then fetch that file from the client via ajax.

Comment: You are creating an extension to the Chrome?

Answer (score 5):

With window.performance API provided by HTML5, there is an easy option to find out the total number of external resources loaded by the page.

```
var totalNoOfResrouces = window.performance.getEntriesByType("resource").length;
```

There is no easy option like finding the individual details like images, css, scripts, etc., But still you can find those if all your resources URL are in some proper format like http://example.com/img/sample.jpg or http://example.com/scripts/app.js or http://example.com/styles/master.css

```
_.filter(window.performance.getEntriesByType("resource"),function(a){ return a.name.indexOf("/img/") > 0 });
```

*note: using _ for filtering. you can use without _. This method also have its own caveats like that it will return only successful requests. Pending resources won't be listed*

Comment: Also having a hard time with this, can you show an example?

Answer (score -1):

You can count the `<link>` and `<script>` manually (for a simple page without ajax).

With JQuery:

```
var requestsNumber = 1; // The document itself.

$('link').each(function() {
    var href = $(this).attr('href');

    if (href && -1 === href.indexOf('http://')) {
        requestNumber++;
    }
});

$('script').each(function() {
    var src = $(this).attr('src');

    if (src && -1 === src.indexOf('http://')) {
        requestNumber++;
    }
});
```

This suppose you correctly use relative url. This won't give you any state for the responses (like 404 for instance). Note that `indexOf` is not working on IE8.

Comment: I can not understand what your answer has to do with the question of "OP", could be clearer? Thanks

Comment: He wants to count the number of requests a page make to the server. In a simple page this is 1 + the number of `script` with a relative src + the number of `link` with a relative href.

Comment: The OP want a solution in "javascript" (I mean using the Chrome dev-tools), so your answer is not what OP need. If you have any idea of how the OP can do it then edit your answer please.

Comment: Hi good answer. A question, `indexOf` not work on IE8? Are you sure?

Comment: You can make it work with a polyfill. You will find one [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/indexOf).

Comment: You don't understand, `indexOf` with `string` in IE8 works, what does not work is `indexOf` with `array`. Your example uses "strings" and not array, so the code should work perfectly in "IE8".

Comment: Oh yes my bad, I'm really not an expert of IE.